# how to create right to left sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, sidenav

i am working on a project where i have to create two sidebar ( left to right for desktop (push sidebar)  -- desktop and right-to-left for mobile ( overlay sidebar ). the desktop push sidebar is working fine and im facing problem in the mobile overlay sidebar.
can u please help me out

link ; http://sidenav-both.surge.sh/

desktop version (pic) working fine
[image]

mobile version (pic)
right now evenever i click on the toggle button  the side nav comes from the left side

[image]

need something like this

[image]

html

```
  <!--   main content goes from here  -->
        <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">


       <!--  Side Navigation  -->
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="custom-menu">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
            </button>
        </div>


        <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"> Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nav 7</a></li>
        </ul>

        </nav> <!-- nav close  -->


        <!-- Page Content  -->

      <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
    
        </div> <!-- row close  -->
     
      </div>
```

css

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  #sidebar {
      /*margin-left: -300px; */
      margin-right: -300px;

    }

  #sidebar.active {
    /*margin-left: 0;*/
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  
  #sidebar .custom-menu {
    margin-right: -60px !important;
    top: 10px !important; 
  }

  #content{
    margin-left: 35px;
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-width` of `#sidebar` to `fit-content;` in the breakpoint of 991.98px.

Also, if you want your sidebar to be thinner, adjust the padding of `ul`.

e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px)
#sidebar {
    /* margin-left: -300px; */
    margin-right: -300px;
    min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```
#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 27px 10px;
}
```